# Wordpress Mailchimp Success Message Customization?

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

How to Customization WordPress MailChimp Success Message in Swedish?

Comment: What script are you using? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Currently looking for this myself... except not sweedish

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the plugin here:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mailchimp/

Use the steps about PO in the FAQ here
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mailchimp/faq/